# OpenIdPortableArea using Razor fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, openid, razor

I'm trying to get the OpenIdPortableArea to work in my ASP.NET MVC site using Razor.

But when I click the Login-link (created by the LoginStatusWidget supplied by a OpenIdPortableArea helper) I get the following error:

> The file '/Views/Shared/Site.Master'
>   does not exist.

That's true of course since I'm using Razor and my "master" is _Layout.cshtml. From the source () of OpenIdPortableArea it looks like it should support Razor views but I cannot understand how.

Anyone got any input on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - the answer was quite simple - that version (1.0.0.3) didn't support Razor.

But just a few days after that a new release was created and 2 different packages on NuGet was added. One for Razor and one for WebForms:
- http://nuget.org/Packages/Packages/Details/OpenIdPortableArea-RazorViews-2-0-0-0
- http://nuget.org/Packages/Packages/Details/OpenIdPortableArea-WebFormsViews-2-0-0-0

That worked much better!